# Как отфильтровать массив по датам и времени, входящим в диапазон?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив

```
const arr =  [
      {
        date: '20.01.2022',
        time: '22:45',
      },
      {
        date: '20.01.2022',
        time: '16:02',
      },
      {
        date: '20.01.2022',
        time: '22:30',
      },
      {
        date: '17.01.2022',
        time: '20:50',
      },
      {
        date: '02.01.2022',
        time: '14:39',
      },
      {
        date: '24.12.2021',
        time: '09:24',
      },
        date: '21.12.2021',
        time: '03:20',
      },
      {
        date: '16.12.2021',
        time: '08:34',
      }
]
```

И есть диапазон, старт - сегодня, конец - 150 дней назад.

```
let range = {
  start: new Date(),
  end: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 150)),
}
```

Нужно отфильтровать массив, чтобы остались только значения, входящие в диапазон. Нужно учитывать также время, так как в массиве есть объекты за один день, но с разным временем.

Comment: И что вы попытались сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать это через `.filter`:

```js
const arr =  [
    {
      date: '20.01.2022',
      time: '22:45',
    },
    {
      date: '20.01.2022',
      time: '16:02',
    },
    {
      date: '20.01.2022',
      time: '22:30',
    },
    {
      date: '17.01.2022',
      time: '20:50',
    },
    {
      date: '02.01.2022',
      time: '14:39',
    },
    {
      date: '24.12.2021',
      time: '09:24',
    },
    {
      date: '21.12.2021',
      time: '03:20',
    },
    {
      date: '16.12.2021',
      time: '08:34',
    }
];

let range = {
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 150)),
};

console.log(arr.filter(object => {
    const splittedDate = object.date.split('.');
    const date = new Date(`${splittedDate[2]}/${splittedDate[1]}/${splittedDate[0]} ${object.time}`); // formatting date
    return date <= range.start && date >= range.end; // check date
}));
```

Comment: Не хотите `object.date.split('.')` вынести?)